# Converting SVG to PNG with RMagick in memory

Tags: ruby, svg, png, rmagick

I'm having a frustrating time converting an SVG string into a PNG string using [RMagick](https://rmagick.github.io/):

```
def convert_svg_to_png(str)
  img = Magick::Image.from_blob(str) {
    self.format = 'SVG'
    self.background_color = 'transparent'
  }
  img.to_blob {
    self.format = 'PNG'
  }
end
```

I get the error: `'convert_svg_to_png': undefined method 'to_blob' for [ SVG 100x10 100x10+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 167b]:Array)`

My only thought is that the `img` instance after `from_blob` is not a `Magick::Image` instance (since the error says it's an `[ SVG ... :Array]`). I haven't found anything online that concretely answers converting an image from SVG to PNG in memory. Lots of mentions of `to_blob` but no workable examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RMagick doc](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#from_blob) for from_blob says that from_blob returns an array of images, so my guess is that this should work:

```
arr = Magick::Image.from_blob(str)
str = arr[0].to_blob
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, after some experimenting I found that I can successfully use `img.to_blob`:

```
def convert_svg_to_png(str)
  img, data = Magick::Image.from_blob(str) {
    self.format = 'SVG'
    self.background_color = 'transparent'
  }
  img.to_blob {
    self.format = 'PNG'
  }
end
```

The key part is the `img, data = Magick::Image...` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

`.to_blob` and `.from_blob` both return an array of images. To get what you want, just call `.first` on the image array and you should have what you need.

```
def convert_svg_to_png(str)
  img = Magick::Image.from_blob(str) {
    self.format = 'SVG'
    self.background_color = 'transparent'
  }
  img.first.to_blob {
    self.format = 'PNG'
  }
end
```

Although the answers provided do work, in this case I find that deconstructing an array during variable assignment to be less legible than just calling `.first` on the generated array. Hope this helps!